# Can't access Wowza REST API

Tags: amazon-ec2, wowza

I'm running Wowza Streaming Engine on an EC2 instance, everything is working except the REST API/REST API documentation.

When I send a request to the rest api or even the documentation I get no response. It times out.

I followed this [guide](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-access-documentation-for-wowza-streaming-engine-rest-api).

Server.xml

```
<RESTInterface>

        <Enable>true</Enable>

        <IPAddress>*</IPAddress>

        <Port>8087</Port>

        <!-- none, basic, digest, remotehttp, digestfile -->

        <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>

        <DiagnosticURLEnable>true</DiagnosticURLEnable>

        <SSLConfig>

            <Enable>false</Enable>

            <KeyStorePath></KeyStorePath>

            <KeyStorePassword></KeyStorePassword>

            <KeyStoreType>JKS</KeyStoreType>

            <SSLProtocol>TLS</SSLProtocol>

            <Algorithm>SunX509</Algorithm>

            <CipherSuites></CipherSuites>

            <Protocols></Protocols>

        </SSLConfig>

        <IPWhiteList>*</IPWhiteList>

        <IPBlackList></IPBlackList>

        <EnableXMLFile>false</EnableXMLFile>

        <DocumentationServerEnable>true</DocumentationServerEnable>

        <DocumentationServerPort>8089</DocumentationServerPort>

        <!-- none, basic, digest, remotehttp, digestfile -->

        <DocumentationServerAuthenticationMethod>none</DocumentationServerAuthenticationMethod>

        <Properties>

        </Properties>

</RESTInterface>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved the problem**
My EC2 instance has an automatically generated security group for Wowza, but it doesn't include access to port 8089 or port 8087 which is what the default Wowza REST API/API docs listen on.

I added the rules to the inbound rules myself for both ports.